# Questioning a user who submitted their nomination at the last minute?

Tags: discussion, election

The nominations for the moderator election have just closed, and one user submitted their nomination at the last possible minute (well, okay, with 4 minutes to go).  There is now no "comment" link on that user's nomination profile.  How can we submit questions to this user that are publicly available for everyone to see?  Do they simply avoid the same individual scrutiny other nominees faced in the comments section of their nomination?

This seems like very poor design.  There are obviously other venues to ask questions (the chat and the now very crowded meta post), but none get the same views as the main election page.  By submitting at the last minute this user has avoided much of the individualized questioning the other nominees endured in the comments section of their nomination post.

Comment: The comments are still visible [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=nomination) (you can switch tabs between "nomination", "primary" and "election" above the line where it says "10 candidates"). However, submission of new comments is now locked, it seems.

Comment: The timing had only to do with the fact that some persuasive folks coaxed me into running late in the day. No need to worry, there is still plenty of time left for discussion.

Comment: @BillDubuque I did not think you were gaming the system at all.  I just thought it was a poor design decision for how the election operates and wanted to say something about it.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best way to question any of the moderator candidates would be to 'attend' the Town Hall chat tonight (more details [in this meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4137/9754)).

If for some reason you won't be able to make it, but you would like to pass some set of questions on to the candidates, I have created a second answer below this answer. It is a CW answer, so all may freely edit it. I will pass on any questions from that answer to the chat tonight (I am a moderator candidate, and I will be attending).

The transcript from the townhall chat will be placed on the meta afterwards for any to read. This has the added advantage of you being able to give Eric Naslund a chance to respond. Due to inconvenient time zones, he will be unable to attend the townhall chat tonight.

Comment: I voted for you as my first choice since your number of helpful flags: $142 \gg $ rest. Other factors include the fact that you are already a mod for phil.se and you competed last time as well. Good luck!

Comment: ^This, plus your uncanny ability to cut to the core of issues and communicate efficiently (as demonstrated in the HW policy question). I care less about the number of flags, though, as I can barely find anything worth flagging in my 100 daily visits!

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of questions to be asked to the moderator-candidates at the [Town Hall Chat](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4137/9754) tonight. This is not an excuse to not attend (please do!), but instead a way for people who are unable to attend to still have the chance to voice their questions.

**Questions**

**0 (example, from mixedmath)**

If elected, will there be free cake? [*not a real question*]

Comment: Perhaps free beer is in order. I also demand a cask of Glen Livet 18.